# Is it feasible to separate numbers by commas every three numbers and round off only in Unix command?

Tags: unix, csv, sed, command

In the following CSV file:

```
name, number, value
Mike, 1000, 21.555522
Justin, 1001, 32.113
Josh, 1002, 998.2101
```

Is it feasible to convert it to the following file?

```
name    number    value
Mike    1,000    21.6
Justin    1,001    32.1
Josh    1,002    998.2
```

Note that the second file is now tab-separated file, since the second column is now separated by commas and hence cannot be used as CSV file any more. Also, I want to round off the value of the third column at one decimal point. And I want to process these tasks only in Unix command, as I don't want to bother to write Python code for such a trivial issue... I assume either `cut` or `sed` makes it feasible, but don't get any answers when I was searching... So please help me get what I wanted.

Thanks.

Comment: And what have YOU tried?

Comment: You should try harder, when searching (which you haven't):
Right-padding string to 80 characters (http://ideatrash.net/2011/01/bash-string-padding-with-sed.html)
`sed -e :a -e 's/^.\{1,80\}$/ &/;ta'`
Converting comma-separated file to tab-separated (http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/24503-converting-tab-delimited-file-comma-delimited-file-unix.html)
`tr '\t' ',' < tab-delimited-file > comma-delimited-file`
Inserting thousands separator (http://superuser.com/questions/392339/how-to-insert-thousand-separator-with-sed)
`sed -r ':L;s=\b([0-9]+)([0-9]{3})\b=\1,\2=g;t L'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F, 'NR==1 { printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n", $1, $2, $3 }
         NR!=1 { printf "%s\t%'\''d\t%.1f\n", $1, $2, $3 }'
```

The sequence `'\''` embeds a single quote into the format string.  `%'d` puts commas into the output.

```
name     number  value
Mike    1,000   21.6
Justin  1,001   32.1
Josh    1,002   998.2
```

Tested on Mac OS X 10.8.4; YMMV.  (The odd alignment on the number and value titles is because of the space after the comma in the data file.)

Comment: Thanks. I got the successful result. So you mean `'\''` is a single quote escape sequence in awk, rather than `\'`, which is adopted in most programming language?

Comment: Actually, no.  The `awk` script is inside (shell) single quotes.  The sequence `'\''` stops the current single-quoted string (the first `'`, inserts an escaped single-quote (`\'`), and starts a new (continuation) single-quoted string (the last `'`).  This is a shell trick for embedding a single quote in a single quoted string.